# How to save a scipy sparse matrix into a parquet file

Tags: python, io, scipy, sparse-matrix, parquet

I am trying to reproduce the setup that was mentioned in the recent [article](https://medium.com/@NetflixTechBlog/introducing-vectorflow-fe10d7f126b8) on the product Vectorflow by Netflix.

They are using parquet files in Hive as the source of data. I would like to generate some fake data with a scipy's sparse matrix. How do I save such a matrix into a parquet file?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @LeoGallucci no, I have not

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache Arrow (Python package name is `pyarrow`) for writing Parquet files: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

There are some convenience functions to store `pandas.DataFrames`, for scipy sparse matrices, you can use some of them but need to adjust it a bit.

The important bit in using Apache Parquet is that is a columnar, table-like format, i.e. it expects a dictionary of arrays. You would have to bring your matrix in this form. This will depend a bit on how Vectorflow expects the data.

Comment: What do you mean adjust it a bit? Is there an example of how to write scipy sparse matrix to parquet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68680184/create-row-column-data-pandas-dataframe-from-sparse-matrix might be related to represent the COO format as columns