# create row, column, data pandas dataframe from sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

How can I create a sparse matrix in the format of COO and have the pandas dataframe not unnest to a dense layout but keep the COO format for `row,column,data`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

a = np.eye(7)
a_csr = csr_matrix(a)
a_coo = a_csr.tocoo()
print(a_coo)
  (0, 0)    1.0
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (3, 3)    1.0
  (4, 4)    1.0
  (5, 5)    1.0
  (6, 6)    1.0
```

I.e. how can I obtain a pandas dataframe from this that does not unnest this to

```
pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(a_coo)
```

[image]

but keeps the `row,column,data` format as also visualized in the `print` operation?

Comment: Basically I want to get the pandas dataframe in the Matrix Market format (MTX).

Comment: `a_coo.row`, `a_coo.col`, `a_coo.data`

Comment: really ;) ok this could have been so easy. Certainly nicer than the mmwrite workaround. Do you want to write this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you want to put in the dataframe are available as

```
a_coo.row, a_coo.col, a_coo.data
```

Answer (score 0):

one possible workaround could be to use mtx serialization and interpreting the data as a CSV.

```
from scipy import io
io.mmwrite('sparse_thing', a_csr)
!cat sparse_thing.mtx

sparse_mtx_mm_df = pd.read_csv('sparse_thing.mtx', sep=' ', skiprows=3, header=None)
sparse_mtx_mm_df.columns = ['row', 'column', 'data_value']
sparse_mtx_mm_df
```

Is there a better (native, non serialization-baased) solution?

```
re_sparsed = coo_matrix((sparse_mtx_mm_df['data_value'].values, (sparse_mtx_mm_df.numpy_row.values, sparse_mtx_mm_df.numpy_column.values)))
re_sparsed.todense()
```

would then give back the initial numpy array